# How do I use a qlineEdit input from one class A in another class B?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in QT and C++, recently I'm writing a program on QT5.7, I have three classes lets say A,B and C, and all have there respective ui.file,h.file and cpp.file, I declared a QLineEdit in ui.file from file A,class A, and now I want use the input of that the user typed in the class B.

I already tried to declare the class A in class B, and in the cpp files but It doesn't seem to work!.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to connect the `textChanged()` signal of your `QLineEdit` to one of the slots of `class B`. This way you will keep getting the changes of `QLineEdit` in class B.

```
// A.cpp
A::A(B *b, QWidget *parent) : 
    QWidget(parent)
{
   // suppose object name of your QLineEdit is 'lineEdit'
   connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
           b, SLOT(TextChanged(QString)));
}

// B.h
class B
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   B();
public slots:
   void TextChanged(QString text);
private:
   QString m_text;
}

// B.cpp
void B::TextChagned(QString text)
{
   m_text = text;
}
```

OR another way is to write a method in Class A to get the text of QLineEdit.

```
// A.cpp
QString A::GetText()
{
   return ui->lineEdit->text();
}
```

Comment: I'm using the second method.

Comment: So the problem now is: how can I take the return string and use it as parameter/query I actually need to use it as a sql query parameter, I tried this:MainWindow userInput;
     userInput.GetText();
     QString parameter = userInput.GetText();
     qDebug()<<parameter;

Comment: Sorry about the comments!

Comment: So the problem now is: how can I take the return string and use it as parameter/query I actually need to use it as a sql query parameter, I tried this:

Comment: MainWindow userInput;                                                                         userInput.GetText();                                                                                 QString parameter = userInput.GetText();                                                                                       but when I try to use parameter in the query statement doesn't work                     qry.exec(" select from xxx where name='"+parameter+"' ");   any help

Answer (score 0):

1) You can pass the class A to the class B method that handle the `QLineEdit`:

```
Class A
{
    public:
        QLineEdit line;
}
class B
{
    public:
        void getText(const A &a) { a.line.text(); }
}
```

2) Or, you can inherit B from A:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        void getText() { line.text(); }
}
```

There is a third way, you can pass A to the constructor of B, but is similar to the first (except you don't have to pass A to all B methods)